# How to make Genymotion android emulator work?

Tags: android, android-emulator, genymotion

I am in a desperate need for an android emulator cause I cannot buy any more device just to test app on different android version.
As stock emulator that comes with Android Studio is just to slow to be of any use I have decided to try Genymotion android emulator version 2.8.1. I have tried that with embedded Oracle Virtual box and I have downoloaded Virtual Box 5.1.14. The problem is that this thing just simply refuses to work.

I have tried emulator for custom phone with version 7.0. The virtual device booted but it was not usable as it has no play store and other stuff. I have downloaded google open apps from http://opengapps.org/. I have used images for x86.
I have installed gapps so that I dragged zipped file to the emulator window, the file was downloaded and an option to flash the device was preseneted. After flash was done I got this repeatable error "google servoces has stopped working" almost once a second. So all I could literaly do was to click Ok on that dialog. I tried clearing data and cache off all apps I could think off. I rebooted counless times... all the same. Google play services and play store simply do not work.

Another observation. After I power down emulatr and try to boot it again I get the error "virtual device cannot be connected" or something like that. The only way I can avoid that Is if I delete the how only network adapter in Virtual box preferences each and every time I want to start emulator. this is annoying.

Since I noticed open gapps makes almost daily builds I tried with a day newer version. This time and all versions afterwards the gapps do not even flash. The zip can be dragged to emulator, a flash option is offered, but the flash process never ends. I have let it tun foir more than 24 hours did not finish.

I have tried this with geny motion emulator for 5.1, 6.0, 7.0 devices. on each of this devices I have tried gapps pico, mini, nano, mikro, mini, full, stock.

Al this has taken me over a week. And not even one combination works. So, my questions are:

Can anybody confirm that genymotion even works so that a google play services and play market can be installed?

Why does my flash never finish?

How to avoid annoying need to delete host only network adapter before each and every emulator run?

Answer (score 0):

Open GApps Pico 20161111 should work with Genymotion Android 7.0 rom. You can find the zips here:
https://github.com/opengapps/x86/releases/tag/20161111

Comment: I took my gapps from http://opengapps.org/. This is what genymotion recomends. But, the problem is that later then 2nd febraury not even one archice I have downloaded does not finish flashing. And I have tried at leat 30 of them.

Comment: Please try the one I pointed out, I am quite confident it is going to work. Direct link to pico for Android 7.0: https://github.com/opengapps/x86/releases/download/20161111/open_gapps-x86-7.0-pico-20161111.zip. If it does not, try from a fresh device, not one where a previous flash install failed.

Comment: Tried it. Similar to my gapps from 2nd february I get "Google play services has stopped" every time I try to add an account or open play store,